# "Unable to Connect to any of the Specified MySQL Hosts" through Xamarin.forms app

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin.forms

I am making a simple registration form using Xamarin.forms which is connected to a MySQL Database. I've watched  [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wD0r6YrC5i0&t=237s) video as a tutorial but it keeps showing me the same error, Unable to Connect to any of the Specified MySQL Hosts.

```
private void RegistrationSubmit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string conString = "Server=localhost; Uid=root; Pwd=ahsan; Database=geolocatordb";
            using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    string query = $"INSERT INTO usercreds(user_name, user_email) VALUES ({Username.Text}, {Email.Text})";
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    RegistrationSubmit.Text = "OK";
                }
                catch(Exception ex) 
                {
                    RegistrationSubmit.Text=ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }
```

Searching Online, i've found that there is some problem in the connection string and i've tried changing the connection string but nothing seems to work.

Comment: `to any of the Specified MySQL Hosts.` Please tell which ones. And tell where your servers are running. Where is the database located? Are you trying to connect to the database itself? Or how?

Comment: @blackapps i'm trying to connect to a localhost server. Also i'm sorry but i'm kinda new to MySQL so i don't really know what you mean by "Where is the database located", its on my PC if that helps.

Comment: Don’t use localhost.  Use the IP or FQDN of the server

Comment: "Its on my PC. Connect to a local host server" What is the connection between the two? What is your setup?

Comment: If you have two pc's and a laptop then what is your local host server? And where is your Android app running? Setup please.

Comment: Everything is setup on my laptop, the app and the Server/Database

Comment: from Android's POV, `localhost` means **the Android device** (or emulator), not the PC that it is hosted on.

Comment: If you are developing a mobile app, then it is unlikely that mysql will ever be hosted locally and it is also inlolely that you will connect a remote mysql directly from a mobile device.